# Is there a way to export an existing dash_table.DataTable as an image (e.g. png, jpg) directly from the Callback?

Tags: python, image, export, plotly-dash

is there a way to export an existing dash_table.DataTable as an image (e.g. png, jpg) directly from the Callback? I tried fig.savefig but that doesn’t work here. Any ideas/directions? See my current Callback below, which returns the data into a nice looking DataTable in the Dash app, but I'd like to also be able to export it as an image.

Thank you in advance!

```
# CALLBACK to return input value
@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='output_report_part4', component_property='children'),
    Input(component_id='advice-dropdown', component_property='value'),
    Input(component_id='expanded-advice-text', component_property='value'),  
)
def update_output_div4(advice, expanded_advice):
    df = {'Metric': ['Advice to purchase the dataset:',
                     'Conclusion with expanded advice:'], 
         'Response': [advice, expanded_advice]}   
    # Create DataFrame  
    df = pd.DataFrame(df)
    fig = dash_table.DataTable(df.to_dict('records'), [{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
#                                style_cell={'textAlign': 'left'},
                                style_header={'backgroundColor': 'rgb(39,64,139)',
                                              'color': 'white'},
                                style_data={'whiteSpace': 'normal',
                                            'height': 'auto'},
                                style_cell_conditional=[
                                            {
                                                'if': {'column_id': c},
                                                'textAlign': 'left'
                                            } for c in ['Metric', 'Data Vendor']
                                                     ],
                                style_cell={
                                            'height': 'auto',
                                            # all three widths are needed
                                            'minWidth': '90px', 'width': '90px', 'maxWidth': '90px',
                                            'whiteSpace': 'normal'
                                            }
                                )
    return fig
```

Answer (score 0):

If dash webserver is running, you could use this package https://pypi.org/project/html2image/ to convert the url to an image.